# How to read a certificate from a string in Go?

Tags: go, ssl, certificate, pem

I'm writing some code that needs to grab certificate content from an environment variable and append it to a certpool.

If I pass the file path of the certificate through the env variable it works fine:

```golang
filename := os.Getenv("CACERT")
b, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Errorf("unable to read root certificate")
}
if ok := pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(b); !ok {
    return nil, errors.Errorf("cannot parse root certificate from %q", filename)
}
```

But if I pass the actual contents of the certificate, `AppendCertsFromPem` throws an error:

```golang
cert := os.Getenv("CACERT")
if ok := pool.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(cert)); !ok {
    return nil, errors.Errorf("cannot parse root certificate")
}
```

This is the string inside the env variable `CACERT`:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

**certificate hash here**

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: What is a “certificate hash”? Is that supposed to be an actual certificate? If it won’t load try parsing it and checking the error manually to see what the error is

Comment: It seems impossible to define bytes in golang file for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is a problem related to golang. It depends on how you set your environment variables. You may be set content with wrong format(newline missed or something else).

My preference is to encode string with newline and other special characters to `base64` and decode it when used.

Comment: You were right...I was missing a new line. thank you very much!